# how to set font size for different IOS devices in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In react-native i design a sample,when i check it in different IOS devices 
here is my code:

```
render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
             <View style={styles.body}>
             <TouchableHighlight style={styles.facebook} >
             <View style={styles.row}>
             <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('image!fb')}/>
             <Text style={styles.facebookText} >Continue with Facebook</Text>
             </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        </View>
      )
  }
};
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    marginTop: 65,
    flexDirection:'column',
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'transparent'
  },
   body:{
    flex:.5
  },
  facebook:{
    marginTop: 25,
    height: 50,
    padding: 10,
    marginRight: 40,
    marginLeft: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#1A8A29',
  },
    row:{
    flexDirection:'row',
  },
  facebookText:{
    marginLeft: 8,
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf:'center'
  },
  icon:{
    marginTop: 3,
     marginLeft: 5,
      width: 25,
      height: 25
    }
})
```

when **i check in iphone-6 and 5s font problem is coming**
any one help me to solve this problem,how to set the font size for different IOS devices in react-native any help much appriciated

Answer (score 11):

<s>I've written the following code for my project:</s>

On the file: `multiResolution.js` I have:

```
export function getCorrectFontSizeForScreen(PixelRatio, screenWidth, screenHeight, currentFont){
  let devRatio = PixelRatio.get();
  let factor = (((screenWidth*devRatio)/320)+((screenHeight*devRatio)/640))/2.0;
  let maxFontDifferFactor = 5; //the maximum pixels of font size we can go up or down
  // console.log("The factor is: "+factor);
  if(factor<=1){
    return currentFont-float2int(maxFontDifferFactor*0.3);
  }else if((factor>=1) && (factor<=1.6)){
    return currentFont-float2int(maxFontDifferFactor*0.1);
  }else if((factor>=1.6) && (factor<=2)){
    return currentFont;
  }else if((factor>=2) && (factor<=3)){
    return currentFont+float2int(maxFontDifferFactor*0.65);
  }else if (factor>=3){
    return currentFont+float2int(maxFontDifferFactor);
  }

}

function float2int (value) {
  return value | 0;
}
```

Then on each react-native component I do:

```
import { PixelRatio } from 'react-native';
import {getCorrectFontSizeForScreen} from './multiResolution' 
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
const {height:h, width:w} = Dimensions.get('window'); // Screen dimensions in current orientation
```

and then on my `styles` I do:

```
var portraitStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  titleText: {
    fontSize: getCorrectFontSizeForScreen(PixelRatio, w,h,27),//magic takes place here
  },
});
```

It's custom but it has worked very well for me.

Also (irrelevant to your question but I'm going to say it anyway), I use widths and heights relevant to the screenWidth and screenHeight like so:

```
aStyleForAnElement:{    //this element will occupy
    width: w*0.55, //55% of the screen width
    height:h*0.05  //5% of the screen height
}
```

This is how I support different screen sizes in my project till now.

**NEW ANSWER:**

As time passes we learn.
At the time I wrote this post I had no other solution to manage font sizes rather than use custom code, but right now I don't have to do any of this:

I simply tell our designer to design for the lowest resolution available 320x480 (and give me the font sizes in points instead of pixels) and then I just use points instead of pixels while designing for 320x480.

All the screens above 320x480 will be taken care of automatically with react-native, I don't have to write ANY fancy code at all to automatically manage that.

My components now simply look like that:

```
BUTTON_TEXT: {
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontSize: 16, // this is 16 points
  color: 'white',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
},
```

Comment: I'm going to put this code into node package.  This is great, thanks!

Comment: dude, its awesome. Thanks for this solution

Comment: I still am using the old solution. If you design for the 5, on everything larger the text is too small

Comment: I'm designing for 5 right now and the text is fine for me..! RN 0.39.2

Answer (score 3):

Only a concept, but I'd try following:

```
const Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
const Viewport = Dimensions.get('window');

const IPHONE6_WIDTH = 750; // check this, since I'm not sure about iPhone 6 width

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getFontSize() {
    return ({
      fontSize: ((Viewport.width * Viewport.scale) === IPHONE6_WIDTH) ? 14 : 16
    });
  }

  render() {
    <View>
      <Text style={[styles.facebookText, this.getFontSize()]}>Continue with Facebook</Text>
    </View>
  }
}
```

Comment: iPhone 6/s plus is (width:  414 scale 3 multiplied together:  1242) --
iPhone 6/s (width:  375 scale 2 multiplied together:  750) -- iphone 5/s (width:  320 scale 2 multiplied together:  640) -- iphone 4s (width:  320 scale 2 multiplied together:  640

Comment: You could also use DeviceInfo.getDeviceId() from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info.

Answer (score 2):

Create a common style for an Application. Reuse this default style properties in all the style components.

**src/common/style.js**

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export const ColorPrimary  = '#5CFE48';
export const SmallPhone = () => {
  if(width<=320) // Here you could use "react-native-device-info" to get device information.
     return true
  else 
     return false
}
```

**In Component style** import the common style file.

```
import { SmallPhone, ColorPrimary } from '../../common/style';
... 
...
const styles =  StyleSheet.create({
  headerLabel: {
    fontSize: SmallPhone() ? 14:26,
    color: ColorPrimary
  }
});
```

You could also directly assign specific font size for each device in common style.js and just simply call the `SmallPhone` function instead of using ternary operators.

Comment: Neat and clean. Thanx a lot for reusable styles.