# How react native Text and Image responsive? smaller text and image in small device, bigger text and image in large device

Tags: responsive-design, react-native

How react native Text and Image responsive?

I only know the Flexbox can make layout responsive but seems can not apply in text and image.

e.g.Make my text and image smaller in iphone 4s, bigger in iphone 6

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Just make text and image smaller in iphone 4s, bigger in iphone 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use Flexbox in order to make your application responsive.

For example, say you wanted to display a line of text and an image on the same line:

```
class ResponsiveExample extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                    Example of centered text
                </Text>
                <Image
                    resizeMode={"contain"}
                    style={styles.image}
                    source={{uri: "your image"}}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-between"
    },
    text: {
        marginLeft: 20,
        flex: 1
    },
    image: {
        marginRight: 20,
        height: 400,
        flex: 3,
    }
});
```

Now the text and image will be displayed relative to the screen size. The usual hangup here is that `flexDirection` defaults to `column`, which will make things line up vertically. You can see what happens when we flip from portrait to landscape orientation:

[image]

As you can see, the text and image respond to the change in orientation.

For a better overview of Flexbox, I like to refer to the following guide:
 https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Just keep in mind that React Native defaults to a `flex-direction` of `column`, so if you want things laid out horizontally, you'll have to explicitly set it to `row`.

Comment: Thanks for your detail tutorial but I want to know is that is there any way to make my text and images smaller when I am running iphone 4s, bigger in iphone 6

Comment: I updated the example to show how you would change the image size based on the screen. Changing font size is going to require a little more engineering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947036/how-to-set-font-size-for-different-ios-devices-in-react-native

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works! One more thing, in a page, I have too many text having too many font size. How can I apply responsive? Do you have any example?

Comment: No problem! If you need different font sizes depending on the screen then create a function that returns the right font size depending on the window's screen size (```require('Dimensions').get("window")```). React Native doesn't yet have percentage-based font calculations. However, there are strong indications that RN will add this functionality in future releases.

Comment: that means I need to calculate those sizes one by one?

Comment: Yes, for now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628677/react-native-responsive-font-size

Answer (score 1):

I think [react-native-fit-image](https://github.com/huiseoul/react-native-fit-image) is useful for you.

> React Native Fit Image enables you to draw responsive image component.

You can use this component as below.

`<FitImage
  source={{ uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png' }}
  style={styles.fitImage}
/>`

Answer (score 0):

You are right to think about Flexbox, simply wrap your Text and Image inside View and make those View flexbox responsive.

Comment: but why my images same size in iphone 4s and iphone 6