# How to solve font size issue in React Native when display zoomed is active in Iphone?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Recently I have face an issue related to font size. In normal case, font size of text are fine but when display zoomed is selected in iphone, app  gets unusable as design gets worse. Is there any way to resolve this in React Native ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947036/how-to-set-font-size-for-different-ios-devices-in-react-native?rq=1

Comment: I think you did not understand my question